# Gave up waiting for root device ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS,
everything was fine and few days ago I got following
error:

`Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/0c65a8c2-a7654613-aa98-16ff0119ceb9 does not exist.
Dropping to a shell!`

and then comes (`initramfs`) prompt. Here I tried `@ sudo update -initramfs -u`
but it is not working.

How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Type `exit` at the prompt and the system should boot.  You should then edit your /boot/grub/menu.lst to wait longer for the root device.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=981159

Comment: thank you for your time,
I typed exit and enter but again (initramfs) prompt came instead of system boot.

Answer (score 1):

Your root device is not ready when `/scripts/local` in initrd trying to mount it. I've the same problem with one of my test servers. The [general solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15515/disk-by-uuid-not-detected-initramfs-boot-failure/15527#15527) is to pass `rootdelay=XXX` to the kernel. However, it doesn't solve my problem.

My workaround for this is to add `sleep NNN` before `maybe_break mount` into `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/init` and update initrd:

- `sudo sed -i 's/maybe_break mount/sleep 5\nmaybe_break mount/g' /usr/share/initramfs-tools/init`
- `sudo update-initramfs -u`